# Why do i get 500 error with my php multi curl request

Tags: php, curl

I need to make 2 POST requests to urls which.
I am able to successfully do them via POSTMAN but I can't seem to get it right in PHP.

I have been crawling stackoverflow for answers and google and I found hints, I have also pulled the php code straight out of POSTMAN to see if I could chain them. I figured out that I needed to do a text file cookiejar because I need to keep the same JSESSIONID, if i dont have that JESSIONID it errors out.

```
<?php
function mycurl($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    $cookie_file = 'C:\Pokemon\cookies.txt';

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    $sub = substr($result, strpos($result, "Set") , strpos($result, ";") - strpos($result, "Set"));
    echo $sub;

    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.URL.com",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => $cookie_file,
        CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => $cookie_file,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "id=A?pokemon=no?digimon=yes",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "cache-control: no-cache",
            "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        ) ,
    ));

    $response2 = curl_exec($ch);
    $err = curl_error($ch);
    echo 'hi';
    echo $response2;

    if ($err)
    {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    }
    else
    {
        echo $response2;
    }

    curl_close($ch);

}
mycurl("https://www.URL.com?id=A");

?>
```

I need to make a POST request with the JESSESSIONID i get from the first curl_exec.

I keep getting this error:

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1 Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 Content-Length: 2508 Date: Fri, 08 Feb 2019 23:25:31 GMT X-Cnection: close
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "id=A?pokemon=no?digimon=yes"` -- shouldn't those question marks be ampersands?

Comment: This is a long shot based on your username, but if you have access to the log files for the API you're talking to you might be able to find out what's wrong with your request by investigating why it's throwing a `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: Sorry Typo my end yes it should be a &...I will try to find out what the nullpointer exception is. Is this the correct way of doing the multi curl request?

Comment: `I figured out that I needed to do a text file cookiejar because I need to keep the same JSESSIONID` - incorrect, go to http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php and _carefully_ read the documentation on `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`

Comment: without knowing the website in question, all we can do is *GUESS* as to why you're getting a HTTP 500. i'm voting to close this question because it contains insufficient code to reproduce the error, and insufficient information to find the answer.

Comment: Could you at least let me know if the php code looks accurate and that i'm not missing anything from that stand point?

Comment: from the docs linked to by @hanshenrik, the file pointed to in the cookiejar option is used *"when the handle is closed, e.g. after a call to curl_close"*. You're not doing that, you're re-using the same curl handle without closing it first. So your second request probably doesn't contain the required cookie.

Comment: I was able to solve this problem using C# instead.